# Is it possible to use a variable such as "['time']['updated']" to parse JSON?

Tags: python, json, parsing, syntax

Ok, json_tree is a variable that contains something that looks like this:

```
    json_tree = "['time']['updated']"
```

Can you pass it as a variable....

```
    hdr = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)' }
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=hdr)
    readdata = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    json_data = readdata.read()
    json_dict = json.loads(json_data)
```

like so??

```
    print(json_dict[json_tree])
```

My purpose is to pass one of many json_tree values from a .ini into the class that contains the above code. 
If this is a bad plan, what could work, instead?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the value of `json_data`? (And no, you cannot evaluate `json_dict[json_tree]`, unless `json_dict` has the key `"['time']['updated']"`, verbatim.)

Comment: Use [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) to read and write ini files.

Comment: BTW, wherever possible, a question title instead of saying "this" should have a description of what "this" is, so someone can tell what you're asking without having to click through to the full question text. I've tried to edit towards that end here.

Comment: Charles - I wanted to do that, but couldn't remember what "this" was. but, it was key values. haha. Thank you.

Comment: DYZ - can you extrapolate on what you mean by "verbatim" in that sentence? Sorry for being obtuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a use case for [`jsonpath`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonpath-rw), in which syntax one would use the expression `time.updated` to refer to the value in question.

```
json_expr = "time.updated"
json_dict = {"time": {"updated": "2018-01-05"}}

from jsonpath_rw import parse as parse_jsonpath

results = parse_jsonpath(json_expr).find(json_dict)
if len(results) == 0:
  raise Exception("Could not find any matches for %r in %r" % (json_expr, json_dict))
elif len(results) > 1:
  raise Exception("Expression %r had more than one match; cannot use for configuration" % (json_expr,))

result = results[0].value
```

Comment: Oh, sweet. As I am a python noob, I had no idea about jsonpath. Going to use this guy. Thank you for the clean solution!

Comment: Just realized this is basically xpath for Python. Pretty great.

Comment: Hey, I have an implementation question...

       json_dict = json.loads(json_data)
        results = parse_jsonpath(self.json_key).find(json_dict)
        print(results)

 coindesk = Price("coindesk","https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json","bpi.usd")

When I run the program, it sends me empty brackets: [] in return.
I know I'm referencing the right json keys.... a bit confused about jsonpath

Comment: Could you ask a new question with a complete [mcve] for that failure mode?

Comment: I created a new question, that is more comprehensive and as minimal as possible, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48629461/python-jsonpath-how-do-i-parse-with-jsonpath-correctly

I appreciate any help you can offer. I have elected to mark your question as the solution, because it is a solution. I am just struggling to use the tool correctly!