# Python, jsonpath: How do I parse with jsonpath correctly?

Tags: python, json, jsonpath

I have an implementation question...

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#This is the API for BTC price request. 
# Average all the amounts, and push that to the program

import json
import urllib.request
from jsonpath_rw import parse as parse_jsonpath

class BtcAPI:

    def __init__(self, url, api_id, json_key):
        self.url = url
        self.api_id = api_id
        self.json_key = json_key

    def btc_api_call(self):

        hdr = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)' }
        req = urllib.request.Request(self.url, headers=hdr)
        readdata = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        json_data = readdata.read()

        json_dict = json.loads(json_data)
        results = parse_jsonpath(self.json_key).find(json_dict)
        print(results)


class Price:


    def __init__(self, api_id, url, json_key):

        self.api_id = api_id
        self.url = url
        self.json_key = json_key

    def pass_for_request(self):

        get_price = BtcAPI(self.url, self.api_id, self.json_key)
        get_price.btc_api_call()


def Coindesk():
    coindesk = Price("coindesk","https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json","time.updated")
coindesk.pass_for_request()
```

The value that gets passed for the "json_key" is "bpi.USD.rate_float"... inside this url. It gets passed to a class called "Price", which creates variables that pass to the class that the code above is contained in.

```
coindesk = Price("coindesk","api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json", "bpi.USD.rate_float")
```

And here is the json I am targeting... trying to get to the rate_float key:

```
{
  "time": {
    "updated": "Feb 5, 2018 18:34:00 UTC",
    "updatedISO": "2018-02-05T18:34:00+00:00",
    "updateduk": "Feb 5, 2018 at 18:34 GMT"
  },
  "disclaimer": "This data was produced from the CoinDesk Bitcoin Price Index (USD). Non-USD currency data converted using hourly conversion rate from openexchangerates.org",
  "chartName": "Bitcoin",
  "bpi": {
    "USD": {
      "code": "USD",
      "symbol": "&#36;",
      "rate": "7,004.9588",
      "description": "United States Dollar",
      "rate_float": 7004.9588
  }
}
```

When I run the program, it sends me the output of the entire json file, rather than the specific key I am trying to target via jsonpath, using "bpi.USD.rate_float"
I'm using jsonpath_rw.

How do I target the rate_float key effectively using jsonpath?

Comment: `parse_jsonpath` does not exist in `jsonpath_rw`. What does it do? What does `time.updated` have to do with the rest of your question? "inside this url"? What url? How do you think that `Price` line will help us if we can't see any of the code for that class? Is it even relevant? Instead of providing us with random fragments of your code that you think are relevant, give us a minimal, complete, working example that reproduces the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. You're probably misunderstanding how something works or there's a bug in the part of the code we can't see.

Comment: Sorry. 
time.updated was a typo. I used it to test if I could target another key. It should be bpi.USD.rate_float.

Comment: Updated to include all code. I believed it was unnecessary need to include the entire body of the code because I suspected the problem was a syntax error... something relatively easy to resolve without extensive testing.

Comment: Please also note the "minimal" I mentioned. You don't need to show us all your code. How much of that code can you get rid of while still demonstrating the problem? E.g. what happens if you replace all of that code by `from jsonpath_rw import parse as parse_jsonpath; results = parse_jsonpath("bpi.USD.rate_float").find({your_actual_dict_goes_here}); print(results)` (with newlines instead of `;`)? Do you still have the same problem?

Comment: Hardcoding the values would defeat the purpose of the class (which will be accessing various urls and targetting different json keys). 
I could modify the code to test it, but it cannot stay that way and achieve what it was written to do.

Comment: The only thing I'm trying to do here is help you figure out where things go wrong. If the minimal code I suggested does in fact work as you would expect, your problem lies not with `jsonpath` but somewhere _else_. E.g. are you sure that HTTP request you're making actually returns the data you expect?

Comment: @mercator The same problem is occuring when I replace the jsonpath variable with the hardcoded path.

Comment: The request is returning the  proper data, and I was able to target the exact value, before, without using json path, but I couldn't pass values between classes the way I did it before. Someone suggested jsonpath, and I'm diving in. Their documentation isn't that great, which is why I'm stumped.

Comment: Please see my prior question, to understand what I am referring to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48602313/is-it-possible-to-use-a-variable-such-as-timeupdated-to-parse-json?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you probably think `results` contains a plain string value from the Python `dict`.

That is not in fact what `jsonpath_rw` returns. If you look at the examples in https://github.com/kennknowles/python-jsonpath-rw you'll see it do e.g.

```
[match.value for match in jsonpath_expr.find({'foo': [{'baz': 1}, {'baz': 2}]})]
```

And as it mentions further down:

> The result of JsonPath.find provide detailed context and path data so it is easy to traverse to parent objects, print full paths to pieces of data, and generate automatic ids.

`find` actually returns a list of objects with contextual information. If all you want is the string value, and you only ever expect to get one return value for your JSONPath expression, you'll need to do something like:

```
results = parse_jsonpath(self.json_key).find(json_dict)
print(results[0].value)
```

Comment: Thank you. This helps a lot. Jsonpath can't be a solution, then, because I need to be able to dynamically access the results via key, and not hardcode an index.

Comment: I have a confused question, however... why would it dump the entire contents of the json file I'm requesting? What is the point of jsonpath at all, if it has no parsing functionality?

Comment: You don't need to hardcode any index. You can also loop over the results, like the example I took from the "documentation" does. It does that in a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). And it doesn't simply dump the entire contents of the json file. It returns a list of objects. Each of those objects contains the value you're after as well as a context object, which allows you to do post-processing, like, say, finding the parents or siblings of the values you found.

Comment: I was definitely being daft. You provided a perfect solution, and all I needed to do was go over it carefully. Thank you for being gracious and thank you for your help!

Answer (score -2):

Here you go with a working Python 3 method:

```
def json_by_jsonpath():
    v_json     = "{\"_id\":{\"oid\":\"55561331552632234577\"},\"profilePatId\":\"123456\",\"patientPatId\":\"123456\",\"comboOrder\":false,\"globalOrderCode\":{\"$numberInt\":\"1\"},\"orderRefNum\":\"621980991862\",\"functionality\":{\"$numberInt\":\"38\"},\"rxType\":{\"$numberInt\":\"1\"},\"orderStoreNum\":\"59382\",\"orderChannel\":\"RR_EM\",\"orderChannelDtls\":\"QULL\",\"scriptDetailRetail\":[{\"rxNum\":{\"$numberInt\":\"274879\"},\"rxStoreNum\":{\"$numberInt\":\"59382\"},\"autoRefillEnabled\":false,\"autoRefillEligible\":false,\"insuranceAvailable\":false,\"sddDrugEligible\":false,\"drugQty\":{\"$numberInt\":\"0\"},\"deliveryInd\":\"1\",\"deliveryComments\":\"Ring bell and drop of in box. This comment is for SDD notes\",\"additionalComments\":\"Please call my insurance and this comment is on notes section\",\"appCode\":{\"$numberInt\":\"291\"}},{\"rxNum\":{\"$numberInt\":\"447902\"},\"rxStoreNum\":{\"$numberInt\":\"59382\"},\"autoRefillEnabled\":false,\"autoRefillEligible\":false,\"insuranceAvailable\":false,\"sddDrugEligible\":false,\"drugQty\":{\"$numberInt\":\"0\"},\"deliveryInd\":\"1\",\"deliveryComments\":\"Ring bell and drop of in box. This comment is for SDD notes\",\"additionalComments\":\"Please call my insurance and this comment is on notes section\",\"appCode\":{\"$numberInt\":\"100\"}}],\"_class\":\"com.rx.repositories.xOrderRetail\"}"


v_jsonpath =  '$._id.oid'  #'$.patientPatId'

        myjson = json.loads(v_json)
    #print(myjson)
    #result_list = [match.value for match in v_jsonpath.find(v_json)]
    #print(result_list)
    json_tag_val = parse(v_jsonpath).find(myjson)
    print(json_tag_val)

    return json_tag_val[0].value
```

Comment: I think you are referring to a library called 'jsonpath-ng' (https://pypi.org/project/jsonpath-ng). 
This is not a build-in functionality for Python3. In fact the library supports Python 2.7 as well. 
For future comments: please add your import and all used libraries. Thank you.